# Multiple notifications in a single user (Laravel 5.6)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Is it possible to have a multiple notifications in a single user? I'm working on this approach. The first notification works with database and broadcast channel. But on the second notification class. It doesn't work.

My second notification class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use App\TideUpdates;
 class NewTideUpdate extends Notification
 {
  use Queueable;
  public $user;


public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}


public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}


public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'tideUpdate' => TideUpdates::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()
    ];
}
 }
```

Comment: Can you add code for how you send this notification and what do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: @TheFallen `$user->notify(new NewTideUpdate($user));`

Comment: And what do you mean by it doesn't work? Do you have some error? Have in mind that the `toDatabase()` method is used to save it and inside the `toArray()` method is what it gets broadcasted.